# How to get ksh to read null fields

Tags: tabs, ksh, delimiter, csv

I have a tab delimited file with some fields potentially containing no data.  In ksh 'read' though treats multiple tabs as a single delimiter. Is there any way to change that behavior so I could have blank data too? I.e. When encountering 2 tabs it would take it as a null field? Or do I have to use awk?

```
# where <TAB> would be a real tab:
while IFS="<TAB>" read a b c d; do echo $c; done < file.txt
```

cf.

```
awk -F"\t" '{print $3}' file.txt
```

The shell version will output the wrong field if the 1st or 2nd record is blank.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible to use modern Korn Shell natively to treat each tab char as a column delimiter such that multiple consecutive tabs will delimit null fields without sed, awk, or perl.
The trick is to set the IFS variable to 2 consecutive tab chars, like so:

```
IFS=$'\t\t'
```

The while loop in the following code will read a tab-separated-values file, putting the fields of each line into a simple indexed array.
The inner for loop simply prints out what it has read, one field per line of output:

```
typeset -a Cols

while IFS=$'\t\t' read -A Cols
do
    for (( i=0 ; i < ${#Cols[@]} ; i++ ))
    do
        print "Cols[$i] '${Cols[$i]}' "
    done
done
```

And yes, this will also properly treat a line *beginning* with a tab char as having a null value for column 1, i.e. in the above **Cols[0]** would be set to null.

I have tested this on /bin/ksh 'AJM93u+ 2012-08-01' on macOS High Sierra
but it should work with AT&T AST open-sourced ksh versions going back 10 years or more. See also https://github.com/att/ast

Answer (score 0):

read will look for the first field, ignoring IFS. Another demonstration of this problem is

```
echo " b c d e"  | while read a b c d e; do echo c=$c; done
```

I'll keep on using a space as the IFS, just a bit easier to test.
Avoiding awk is possible with cut:

```
echo c=$(echo " b c d e"  | cut -d" " -f3)
```

When you want to assign all fields in one run, you will be stuck with cut.
Sed accepts different -e options and work on them in the order given.
You can get the fields by

```
eval $(echo " b c d e"  | 
   sed -e 's/^/a=/' -e 's/ /;b=/' -e 's/ /;c=/' -e 's/ /;d=/' -e 's/ /;e=/')
echo check:
set | grep "^[a-e]="
```

Do you trust your input or do you prefer awk above sed?